# On a single click a form submits twice

Tags: php, javascript, form-submit, double-submit-problem

I have a `PHP` file with a big form (about 10-15 fields) and even more `hidden inputs`.

There is no action entry and no `onSubmit` either. `However` forms getting submitted chiefly through 2 links i.e

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return save_change('abc');" >
     <img src="qimages/publish-to-world.jpg" alt="Publish to world" border="0" />
</a>
```

And the other submit form is like this

```
<td id='save_td'>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return save_change('save');" class="thickbox">
        Save as draft
     </a>
 </td>
```

`save_change` is a pretty large function which validates the inputs and returns false if not validated and submits form if validated.

**The problem is that : only sometimes for the remote clients who are accessing this page the form is submitting twice on a single click -- not always.**

We are not able to replicate the issue at our end

Comment: can you post your html and javascript code ?

Comment: @DevangRathod may be he has top secret code inside js or html..

Comment: if you are not at all able to replicate the error at your system, ask the client user to give remote access to his system and verify yourself what the errors are.Coz with out knowing the actual problem fix is not possible.There are so many tools like teamweaver available for remove connect.Or you will have to post the code here as Rathod said, then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I have asked for team viewer access from the client. and would be getting the same by this afternoon. with regards to the code. the code is pretty big.. i need to see what exact portion i need to publish

Comment: @Aravind:Check for the js form submit codes, and check for the conditions in which you use js codes to submit form which may be the reason.only a guess.